# FAILARCHPATH not working for Db2 database

Tags: db2

Logarchmeth and failarchpath configured to different local disk paths and I made the Logarchmeth path unavailable (removing the privileges)

- Failarchpath path was still not used at any point (all the logs were kept in the log path), but the database was up and running for the whole time
- Once the Logarchmeth path got available again, the backup restarted.

Don't understand why logs were not backed up to the location pointed to by failarchmeth setting.

Comment: I assume, that you mean log file archiving, not a database backup. What do you get with the following? "db2 connect to *MYDBNAME*; db2 get db cfg show detail | grep -i 'failarchpath'". Are you able to run successfully the following command as an instance owner? "touch /path/you_specified_for_failarchpath/${DB2INSTANCE}/MYDBNAME/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/test.txt".

Comment: Hello Mark, for the first command the output is "Failover log archive path                (FAILARCHPATH) = /home/db2inst1/failover_archive/". It is a valid directory. And yes, I am able to successfully touch/create file in the path you mentioned.

Comment: The reason I asked this question was to check, if this setting of db cfg parameter is active. It's probably more convenient to run this command: `db2 get db cfg show detail | grep -E "Description|FAILARCH"`. So, do you see this string twice in the output - as current and delayed value?

Comment: Yes, we see the string twice.  Description                                   Parameter   Current Value              Delayed Value
 Failover log archive path                (FAILARCHPATH) = /home/db2inst1/failover_archive/ /home/db2inst1/failover_archive/

Comment: Open a Case with IBM support then. It's not correct behavior, and I don't see it on my test system.